# JavaScript/D3: Create floating textbox on click and update graph from textbox input

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to plot multiple interactive lines using D3. When each of the line is clicked, a floating textbox should show up based on current mouse coordinates and wait for an input to update the line coordinates. Once the textbox is changed, the line should update automatically and the textbox should disappear. Can someone take a look at my code and figure out what went wrong? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="d3_line"></div>
    <script>
        var svg = d3.select("#d3_line").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 800)
            .attr("height", 800);
        line1 = {
            "x1": 100,
            "y1": 50,
            "x2": 750,
            "y2": 500
        };
        line2 = {
            "x1": 100,
            "y1": 200,
            "x2": 750,
            "y2": 650
        };
        data = [];
        data.push(line1);
        data.push(line2);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var line = d3.select("svg")
                .append("svg:line")
                .attr("id", ("line" + i))
                .attr("x1", data[i].x1)
                .attr("y1", data[i].y1)
                .attr("x2", data[i].x2)
                .attr("y2", data[i].y2)
                .style("stroke", "black")
                .style("stroke-width", 6)
                .on("click", function (d) {
                    var lineTextbox = $("svg").append("div").attr("id", "lineTextbox").style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 20) + "px").style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 40) + "px");
                    lineTextbox.html("new x1: <input type='text' id=new_x1></input>");
                    d3.select("#line" + i).on("change", function () {
                        this.attr("x1", $("#lineTextbox").val());
                        $("#lineTextbox").remove();
                    });
                });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Notwithstanding many problems with the code, such as attempting to append an `input` element via another element's `.html` property, the greatest problem is: you are appending html elements to the `svg:svg` element. It will not work like this. Please look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492289/extending-d3-tree-layout-to-provide-html-box-at-final-node#23495971) for some guidance.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes Thanks for this! I figured it out. Do you mind copy and paste my answer and post it? I really want to give you credits for this.

Comment: That is really kind of you and very much appreciated. But I have a suggestion: since you figured it out and did the work yourself (which is great!) you can go ahead and post your answer. It is totally acceptable to do so. Congrats :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @FernOfTheAndes pointed out, the idea is really to append a foreign object to `svg`, instead of appending input element to a `html` property.

```js
var svg = d3.select("#d3_line").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 800)
            .attr("height", 800);
line1 = {
    "x1": 100,
    "y1": 50,
    "x2": 750,
    "y2": 500
};
line2 = {
    "x1": 100,
    "y1": 200,
    "x2": 750,
    "y2": 650
};
var data = [];
data.push(line1);
data.push(line2);
var lineID = "";

function update() {
    d3.select("#" + lineID).attr("x1", $("#new_x1").val());
    $("#new_x1").remove();
}

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var line = d3.select("svg")
        .append("svg:line")
        .attr("id", ("line" + i))
        .attr("x1", data[i].x1)
        .attr("y1", data[i].y1)
        .attr("x2", data[i].x2)
        .attr("y2", data[i].y2)
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("stroke-width", 6)
        .on("click", function () {
            $(".externalObject").remove();
            lineID = d3.select(this).attr("id");
            svg.append("foreignObject")
                .attr("class", "externalObject")
                .attr("x", (d3.event.pageX - 20) + "px")
                .attr("y", (d3.event.pageY - 40) + "px")
                .attr("width", 200)
                .attr("height", 100)
                .append("xhtml:div")
                .html("<input type='text' id=new_x1 placeholder='input new x1 here' onchange=update()></input>");
        });
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<div id="d3_line"></div>
```